# Table Partitioning in SP1 for SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, service-pack

Can anyone validate\conclude for sure if SP1 for SQL Server 2016 now makes Table Partitioning available in the Standard Edition version? It has always been an Enterprise Edition feature in the past. I have seen this on a few blogs, but is this true?

Thank You,
Max

Comment: so says Microsoft - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/11/16/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-generally-available/

Answer (score 9):

I can do one better than Standard Edition, here is proof that it is available even in Express Edition ([click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H68PX.png)):

> [image]

As are all of the other features "they say" are enabled. Everything in [this post](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1) is true, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. You can read a summarized version of what 2016 SP1 brings to Standard Edition [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/11/sql-server-2016/big-deal-sp1)

However, as always, I'd recommend that you truly evaluate your actual needs before diving into partitioning. It is primarily a data management feature that sometimes allows for performance improvement (by partition elimination) in an extremely-controlled query environment.

Comment: Hi, yes, this is a feature that we had here before I started. It is used to partition a very large table into 4 parts for performance improvements in R\W. They way I have it is each partition sits in it's own FG and each FG sits on a different RAID 1+0 array. Makes it very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning even works under Compatibility mode.  tested it with compatibility 120 (SQL 2014 mode) and Standard edition.